# Django view works for only one url ,despite the appropriate queryset being generated in the view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-filters

I am trying to access a lesson belonging to a course in my application. When I use the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/1/" the appropriate results get returned. However when I try anyother url such as "http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/2/" I get an error instead
Result for  http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/1/

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "course 1 lessson 1",
    "owner": 1,
    "course": 1
}
```

Expected Result for  http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/2/

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "course 1 lessson 2",
    "owner": 1,
    "course": 1
}
```

actual result

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

URL

```
 path('courses/<int:pk>/lessons/<int:lpk>/', LessonDetail.as_view()),
```

Serializer

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ['id','title','owner','course']
```

view

```
class LessonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
       # GET PK FROM URL USING KWARGS
        course_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        lesson_pk = self.kwargs['lpk']
        qs = Lesson.objects.filter(course_id=course_pk,id=lesson_pk)
        print(qs)
        return qs
```

model

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter course title')
    video = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter course title', null=True)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter course title', null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='lessons')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the course')
    owner = models.ForeignKey( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  )
```

The view returns the object `<QuerySet [<Lesson: course 1 lessson 1>]>` for http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/1/
and `<QuerySet [<Lesson: course 1 lessson 2>]>` for http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/lessons/2/. To my inexperienced eye, it looks as if the view is returning the appropriate queryset but it fails to produce any results for the second url. How can I make it respond appropriately.

Comment: Actually I guess that there is no error in code. Check that you have `<Lesson 2>` in your database.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have a lesson 2. The code doesn't work for any combination except course 1 lesson 1@FaisalManzer

Comment: It is `get_object`, not `get_queryset`, that you should override here (and it should use get not filter).

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you it works now. However I cant seem to mark your comment as the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You also can use **generics.RetrieveAPIView** for DetailView. Than declare *queryset and serializer_class*.